# Can I somehow link parameter inside loop which is inside loop with parameter inside first loop?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    cout << "how many elements? " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    int arr[x];
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        cout << "give number" << endl;
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
//  for(int i = y; i >= 0; i-z)
    while (z < x)
    {
        for(int i = y; i < x; i++)
        {
            for(int i = z; i < x-y; i++)
            {
                cout << arr[i] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            y++;
        }
        z++;
        cout << z;
    }
//  while (z < x);
    return 0;
}
```

I want my parameter `z`, which is in the `while` loop, to link with parameter `i=z` in the second `for` loop. I want the program to print numbers from 1 to `n`, then from 2 to `n`, and so on, to the moment it will print only `n`.

Don't mind this `cout<<z;` in line 30, I was checking if this even works.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: For starters, use different variable names for the loop variables.  e.g.:  use `i` in the outer loop and `j` in the inner loop.  Then you can refer to `i` in crafting your inner loop.

Comment: `int arr[x];` is [not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/) when `x` is not a compile-time constant. Use `std::vector` instead when you don't know the array size at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by "link with z", but here is what the loop should be to do what you want it to:

```
for (int z = 0; z < x; ++z) // NOTE: get rid of outside z
    {
        for(int i{z}; i < x; ++i)
            std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

The inner loop loops through all of the values of the array, starting with z and ending at x-1. Since z is incremented, the next loop will start at the next position, starting at what was z plus one and ending at x-1.

Also change:

```
int arr[x];
```

To:

```
int* arr = new int[x];
```

and add this line at the end:

```
delete [] arr;
```

This should be added and changed because C++ doesn't support variable length arrays. However, it does support pointers to blocks of memory treated as arrays. You also should delete memory you use when you are done with it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil will edit

Comment: It's probably clearer to express that while loop as a for loop `for(int z=0; z<x; z++)`

Comment: @SirGuy will edit, though I was trying to change Blaze's code the least amount I had to.

Answer (score 2):

In c++, while declaring an array either the size or the elements must be known at the time of compilation, if you want to declare an array during run time, you can do one of the following

- you can use `std::vector`, which is a dynamically growing array, and can be initialized without the size or elements, it is included in the `vector` header file.
- use the `new` keyword to dynamically allocate a block of memory on the heap which returns a pointer and will act as your array (refer to @captainhatteras 's answer)

However it is better to use vector in this case as it is much more easier to understand and use

And you don't need the nested loop here, (not sure if you were keeping it for future reference, i removed it for the sake of simplicity)

**How it works**

Here with each iteration of the while loop, we're incrementing the value of `int z` which is taken as the starting point of our `for-loop`, therefore with each passing iteration the range of the `for-loop` is decreased by 1. ultimately the value of `int z` will be equal to `int x` and the code will exit the while loop

so your code would look something like this

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x, z = 0;
    cout << "how many elements? " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    vector<int> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        int choice;
        cout << "give number" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        arr.push_back(choice);
    }
    cout << endl;
    while (z < x) {
        for (int i = z; i < x; i++)
            std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
        z++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`std::vector` has a method called `push_back()` which adds an element passed in to the end of the array

Comment: Since Blaze already knows the size of the array from the input x, vector here should not be used, as push_back can cause reallocation.

Comment: yea ill edit my answer one sec

Comment: @CaptainHatteras It's fine to use a vector in such a case and just use `reserve` if you're concerned about reallocations. It's certainly preferable to manual memory management.

Comment: It's probably clearer to express that while loop as a for loop `for(int z=0; z<x; z++)`

Comment: @Kyle so keep this answer? or add dynamic allocation

Comment: @AnanthDev I'd keep it as is. Maybe add a `reserve` call if you're so inclined with a comment about what it does, but I wouldn't worry too much about it. There's many more pitfalls with a direct dynamic allocation than just letting `vector` take care of everything.

Comment: ah alright thanks for the feedback :)